# Iteratively save .Rds data.frame objects with R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, save

I need to save iteratively `data.frame` objects on drive.

A similar issue was already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29236654/2950721) but ultimately, and to my point of view, missed the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29237088/2950721) because:

1. The author of the question correctly asked to save the `data.frame` as `.Rds` file, but ended up writing code about `.Rda`;
2. The author of the accepted answer uses `save()` whereas `saveRDS()` should have been used. Failing to do so, command `readRDS` won't read corresponding files.

My question:

- What piece of code do I need in order to iteratively save `.Rds` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here below is a piece of, hopefully reproducible, piece of code (with comments) that worked very well for me (links in comments are where code has been found to adapt to situation):

```
# 1. Load some data from the Internet and close connections
library(quantmod)
tickers <- c("SHOP", "MPNGF", "BABA", "JD")
getSymbols.yahoo(tickers, auto.assign = TRUE, env = globalenv())
closeAllConnections()


# 2. Find all loaded xts files
xtsObjects <- names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts))))


# 3. Iteratively convert found xts files under 2. into data.frames
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/69246047/2950721
library(zoo)
for (i in seq_along(xtsObjects)) {
  assign(xtsObjects[i], fortify.zoo(get(xtsObjects[i])))
}

# 4. Iteratively save converted data.frame objects as .Rds files
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345810/2950721
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/69246047/2950721
library(fs)
rdsFilesFolder <- path("rdsFiles")
saveRDSobjects <- paste0("./", rdsFilesFolder, "/", xtsObjects, ".Rds")

for (i in seq_along(xtsObjects)) {
  saveRDS(get(xtsObjects[i]), file = saveRDSobjects[i])
}
```

---

System used:

- R version: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
- RStudio version: 1.4.1717
- OS: macOS Catalina version 10.15.7